# Time() function in PHP

Tags: php

I just wanted to ask, since I'm coding a script, and I'm using `time()` as a salt for what I am doing.

Now what's happening is I'm salting the data sent from server 1, to server 2. Server 2 checks to see if the `data = submitted_data + time()` matches exactly. And I wanted to know, since my script will be used on different servers, will the `time()` function return the same value (if they're located in different parts of the world?)

A code example from the client is:

```
if($return == md5("true" . time()))
```

And a code example, where if the data that's submitted correctly, will return this:

```
echo md5('true' . time());
```

Both are on different servers in different parts of the world, but I wanted to know if using the `time()` will mess up the way my system's going to work..?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on it. If the clocks aren't in sync, you'll get errors.

Comment: Would I be able to use something like time(hour:minute) and not have to have seconds included?

Comment: You might then have a problem every 60 seconds. That sounds completely unreliable to me.

Comment: What makes you think time on two machines would ever be the same unless you have NTP running?

Comment: I see.. I saw time() as the best option to use, because I wanted a SALT that changes every minute, but returns the same value on EVERY server over the world. I don't know how I'm going to overcome such a problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do — message authentication? Be *very* careful about it. You may be vulnerable to hash-extension attacks or something of the like. If possible, use someone else's library.

Comment: http://php.net/gmdate might be a better idea...but even then, I wouldn't say it could be relied on for every server

Comment: I am safe, since the code before and after in both the client and server scripts are secured to make sure it returns the correct data. But all I needed to know is if time() is the same on every server. Because it seems to be working from my localhost, I'm in Australia, and my server in US. But I think I'd be best off using H:M instead of H:M:S?

Comment: Why not change the salt every usage, rather than every minute?

Comment: and if you have both servers times synced, what you can do with the delay time in sending/receiving data to the second server?

Comment: How would I have the salt change every usage? Both scripts are on different servers, one's the client and one's the host/master which has all the switches to control the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try following :

echo  date("Y-m-d H:i")
echo  strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i"));

Value of strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i")); would not change until you pass the next minute OR you can remove "i" based on your requirement.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What does the Y m d H i stand for? Would this be the best method to use if i was going to use time salting?

Comment: Y is for year, m => for month, d for day, H => for hour, i =>minute..    Why don't you have a look at "mcrypt_create_iv" or "mt_rand" based on your requirements

Comment: Ohhh, right. And what is the H:i for? And since I'd be using date instead of time.. Is it the same value for every server/location? Or does it return the date of the server the script's on?

Comment: Though I would not suggest you to use anything based on time for salting unless it is the last option for you

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because `time()` relies on the system's local clock, which is pretty much guaranteed to not be in sync between any two computers/clocks. Secondly, you cannot guarantee when a given process will be given time by the operating system to run; therefore one server may be milliseconds off simply because it was doing something else intensive. Then you have network latency, etc. etc.

This is a significant issue with distributed systems, which have to keep things 'in sync' without knowing precisely when which actions occurred. (Should this update to the db happen before that one, if the database is spread across multiple servers?) It is best to not rely on time for that reason, but perhaps some other thing, such as a revision number (which is then incremented). For instance:

- The server sends down data with revision id = 142 (Note '142' is arbitrary for this example)
- The client makes a change, increments the revision and hashes that.
- The client sends the data to the server with the hashed revision number.
- The server increments it's own revision id and hashes it. This should now equal what the client sent.
- If it doesn't, the server rejects the data send.

This gets you the ability to simulate time without relying on an inconsistent external resource.

Comment: I see, but for some reason my localhost, which I am in Australia and my server, which is in the US - the script works, but sometimes doesn't every now and then.. But is there any other option I could choose instead of time()? Is there a possible way to have time(HH:SS) HH being hour and SS being second?

Comment: See my revision, but note that HH:SS may occasionally fail as well for the same reason; suppose it takes only a microsecond to send and process, but in that time the 'second' ticks over to the next second?